How Can I Download AVD Manager & Android SDK Without Android Studio
Can anyone please help me download AVD manager & Android SDK tools/folder without installing Android Studio, I will use it on VS Code editor when I go to create an emulator on vs code it shows this message avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK
Without installing Android Studio, I want to download Android SDK & AVD manager for vs code.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


Download Command-Line Tools:


Download the Command Line Tools package for your operating system from the Android Developer website
Windows:
download
Mac:
download
Linux:
download

This package includes the necessary tools like the sdkmanager and the avdmanager files, which are used to manage SDK packages and AVDs, respectively.



Extract Android SDK Tools:


Extract the downloaded zip file to a location on your computer.
Inside the extracted folder, you will find sdkmanager and other tools.


Define the bin address in the OS environment variable.

nano ~/.zshrc
export PATH=$PATH:<path_to_sdk>/cmdline-tools/latest/bin


For instance:

nano ~/.zshrc
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/doran/Android/cmdline-tools/latest/bin


And apply it:

source ~/.zshrc


Install SDK Components:


Open a terminal (or command prompt on Windows), and navigate to the folder where you extracted the command-line tools.
Install the required SDK packages by the following command:

sdkmanager --update


Install AVD Manager Tools:

sdkmanager "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86_64"


This installs the system image needed to create AVDs. Replace android-30 with the version you need.


Create an AVD:


To create a new AVD run the following command

avdmanager create avd -n <AVD_Name> -k "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86_64"


Replace <AVD_Name> with your desired name for the virtual device.


Launch the AVD:

emulator -avd <AVD_Name>


Make sure you have a compatible Java Development Kit (JDK) installed on your system, as it is required for using the SDK tools.

